# Export Gridview to Excel: Cannot export the correct data displayed

Tags: c#, .net, export-to-excel

I need to export my gridview data to excel. No problems for this.
All works correctly
The problem is i can apply filters to the data displayed in the grid. And when i want to export only those data (once the filter is applied), it exports ALL the data contained previously in my grid before the filter.

I hope i'm clear enough...

This is the code i'm using:

```
    public void ExportGridToExcel(GridView grdGridView, string fileName)
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;

        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=GridViewExport.xls");
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

        grdGridView.AllowPaging = false;
        grdGridView.DataBind();

        //Change the Header Row back to white color
        grdGridView.HeaderRow.Style.Add("background-color", "#FFFFFF");

        // Apply style to Individual Cells
        grdGridView.HeaderRow.Cells[0].Style.Add("background-color", "green");
        grdGridView.HeaderRow.Cells[1].Style.Add("background-color", "green");
        grdGridView.HeaderRow.Cells[2].Style.Add("background-color", "green");
        grdGridView.HeaderRow.Cells[3].Style.Add("background-color", "green");
        grdGridView.HeaderRow.Cells[4].Style.Add("background-color", "green");
        grdGridView.HeaderRow.Cells[5].Style.Add("background-color", "green");
        grdGridView.HeaderRow.Cells[6].Style.Add("background-color", "green");

        for (int i = 0; i < grdGridView.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            GridViewRow row = grdGridView.Rows[i];

            // Change Color back to white
            row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            // Apply text style to each Row
            row.Attributes.Add("class", "textmode");
            // Apply style to Individual Cells of Alternating Row
            if (i % 2 != 0)
            {
                row.Cells[0].Style.Add("background-color", "#C2D69B");
                row.Cells[1].Style.Add("background-color", "#C2D69B");
                row.Cells[2].Style.Add("background-color", "#C2D69B");
                row.Cells[3].Style.Add("background-color", "#C2D69B");
                row.Cells[4].Style.Add("background-color", "#C2D69B");
                row.Cells[5].Style.Add("background-color", "#C2D69B");
                row.Cells[6].Style.Add("background-color", "#C2D69B");
            }
        }
        grdGridView.RenderControl(hw);

        // style to format numbers to string
        string style = @"<style> .textmode { mso-number-format:\@; } </style>";
        Response.Write(style);
        Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
    }
```

What i do to apply filters ( all works perfectly )

```
    public void refreshGridFactures()
    {
        DateTime? debutFacture = null;
        DateTime? FinFacture = null;
        DateTime? DebutReglement = null;
        DateTime? FinReglement = null;
        int? NumeroFacture = 0;

        if (PickerDateDebut.SelectedDate != null) { debutFacture = PickerDateDebut.SelectedDate; }
        if (PickerDateFin.SelectedDate != null) { FinFacture = PickerDateFin.SelectedDate; }
        if (PickerDebutReglement.SelectedDate != null) { DebutReglement = PickerDebutReglement.SelectedDate; }
        if (PickerFinReglement.SelectedDate != null) { FinReglement = PickerFinReglement.SelectedDate; }
        int IdEntreprise = Convert.ToInt32(ddlEntreprises.SelectedValue);
        string Intitule = txtIntitule.Text;
        if (txtNumeroFacture.Text != "") { NumeroFacture = Convert.ToInt32(txtNumeroFacture.Text); }

        List<DBAccess.Facturation> listFacturation = DBAccess.DAOFacturation.GetFactures(IdEntreprise, debutFacture, FinFacture, DebutReglement, FinReglement, Intitule, NumeroFacture);
        GridFactures.DataSource = listFacturation;
        GridFactures.DataBind();

        double total = Math.Round(listFacturation.Sum(a => a.MontantTTC), 2);
        double totalHT = Math.Round(listFacturation.Sum(a => a.MontantHT), 2);

        lblTotalTTC.Text = "Montant total TTC : " + total;
        lblTotalHT.Text = "Montant total HT : " + totalHT;
    }
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Actually you're exporting to HTML since `grdGridView.RenderControl(hw)` will create a table ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right after your `GridViewRow row = grdGridView.Rows[i];` add a check to see if the row is visible

`if(!row.Visible) continue;`